# ExpandableList in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've been working on this few days ago, but I need some guide here (I'm newbie to Android programming).

In Api Demos there are 3 examples explaining how to fill a ExpandableList with data, one with arrays, other with List and the third with 2 cursors.

So, suppose I want to have for example 3 categories: Video, Audio and Images and I want to fill this parents with MediaStore.Video cursor, MediaStore.Images cursor ...

Should I have to create an personalized adapter for this? Because for Video Audio and Images y can create an array of Strings, but for the content inside in those categories I have to make a cursor to get the data and then fill inside the parents.

Suggestions?

Thx

Comment: This is just an opinion, I used `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and the ArrayList example from the samples folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest thing to do is to extend the BaseExpandableListAdapter and create an "ExpandableListAdapterAdapter".  In other words, i created an adapter that i can add adapters as groups and the corresponding headers to.  This way, anytime i need to add a new group i can just add a new adapter.  Also, this class is flexible and i can reuse in any other project that i need an expandable list for.